# Execute code if kernel is interrupted (Python in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am running a function in a Jupyter notebook and I would like to know if it's possible to execute a bit of code if the user interrupts the kernel.

For example if you have this function:

```
import time
def time_sleep():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('hello')
```

Can I add a `print('cell terminated')` that runs if the cell is interrputed ?

Comment: Have you tried `try: catch KeyboardInterrupt:`? I'm not sure whether Jupyter sends a real interrupt signal to the kernel, but if it does, that might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keyboard interrupts (ctrl+c) manifest as `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, so

```py
try: 
    time.sleep(5)
    print('That was a nice nap.')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('What a rude awakening!')
```

works if Jupyter sends a real interrupt signal to the kernel (and apparently it does!).